# Java, 2d array of boolean values && comparison

Tags: java

This is back to the beginning of Java 101, but I have this code here:

```
    if ((d==3)&&(City.walls[x--][y])){
        System.out.println ("Fourth Condition true");
        System.out.println (City.walls[x--][y]);
        return false;
    }
```

Even if `City.walls[x--][y]`) is false, and `System.out.println` confirms this by printing out false, it will still enter the if statement, no matter what. What am I doing wrong with the comparison? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That code looks fine to me. Bear in mind, though, that `x--` will change the value of `x`, so whatever x was before the if block, it will be one less inside the block, possibly giving you a misleading debugging statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using x--, which changes the value of x. First it returns the value, then it decrements the value:

```
int x = 5;
System.out.println(x--); //outputs 5
System.out.println(x);   //outputs 4
```

You probably want to say x-1

Answer (score 2):

The values will be different when your code executes in `if` condition and then inside `if` condition where you are printing in console.

You are decrementing value of x in the if condition. 
So, When you print it inside condition you will get decremented value.